# Set delegate:self.delegate in an alertView where self.delegate implements UIAlertViewDelegate protocol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

In my ViewController I have implemented the UIAlertViewDelegate and in my Model I have a method which creates an UIAlertView with the delegate set to self.delegate which is an instance of the ViewController. Then I try to call willPresentAlertView like this (in Model):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid operation"
            message:@"Cannot divide by 0!"
            delegate:self.delegate
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
            otherButtonTitles:@"Undo division",nil];
[self.delegate willPresentAlertView:alert];
```

The willPresentAlertView is implemented in ViewController like this:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [alertView show];
}
```

I then get an error **Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,adress=0xbf7fff6c)** when calling `[alert show]`.

If I set delegate to `nil` or self it works fine, but I want to call `alertView:alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex` when I press a button on the alert, which doesn't work with delegate set to nil or self. Only the ViewController implements these methods, why it should be self.delegate, or?

I want the model to invoke the alert, but I want the ViewController to handle the alert methods such as `alertView:alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

it should be self `[self willPresentAlertView:alert]`

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid operation"
            message:@"Cannot divide by 0!"
            delegate:self //self
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
            otherButtonTitles:@"Undo division",nil];
[self willPresentAlertView:alert];//self again
```